# Look up Cell data based on Month header in table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

i'm trying to create a small spreadsheet for data verification.
Below i have created two tables Table 1 and Table 2.

What i am trying to find is a simple =Index Match or similar to check for Current month then copy that value to respective Group row under verification.

Problem is that the months are a header row and i have no idea how to check a header row for correct month then output the values in the cells below it to each corresponding group in the output list.

So to put it in programming terms this is what im looking for

```
If A2=Table2[Header] then c8=C4 else table[header] + step right
```

A2 contains todays Date (=today()) and Header has the shorten Month names as Jan Feb Mar and so on.
Something similar as above, i don't know if i'm making it harder for me then it really should be. I'm working with Excel 2013.

```
Output list
Group    Input  Verification  Differance
G1       120    123           =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])
G2        76    110           =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])
G3       110    90            =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])
G4        34    53            =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])

Data list
Group    Year   Jan Feb Mar Apr 
G1       2017       123 95  80                              
G2       2017       110 85  75                              
G3       2017       90  80  70                              
G4       2017       53  53  46
```

Regards
Johan

Comment: Then month names in the header, are they dates formatted as `mmm` or are the just text strings?

Comment: They are formatted as string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a second match to find the correct column:

```
=INDEX(DataList,MATCH([@Group],DataList[Group],0),MATCH(TEXT($A$1,"mmm"),DataList[#Headers],0))
```

[image]

Comment: You beat me Scott on this. :)

Comment: And if you don't want to use Cell A1 for date reference, than simply use `(TEXT(TODAY(),"MMM")` instead.

Comment: @ManishChristian though I would recommend using one cell to hold the date as `=Today` is a volatile function and limiting the number of volatile functions is always a good idea.  This way the bulk of the formulas only will recalculate if the day date in A1 changes and not every time Excel recalculates.

Comment: Good stuff. Make sense.

Comment: Thank you Scott! This worked like a charm, only think i noticed was that I needed to use MMM instead of mmm otherwise it was flawless! Thank you once again