# Look up Cell data based on Month header in table with two cells as reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Some days ago i got [help from Scott Craner with an formula for a 3D index match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42394092/4628637) which works great.

I have tried expanding on it without any results, hopefully you can point out what i'm doing wrong.

```
Output list
Group Division   Input  Verification  Differance
G1       1        120     123           =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])
G2       2         76     110           =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])
G3       3        110      90           =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])
G4       4         34      53           =Sum([@[Input]]-[@[Verification])

Data list
Group Division    Year   Jan Feb Mar Apr 
G1        1       2017       123 95  80                              
G2        2       2017       110 85  75                              
G3        3       2017       90  80  70                              
G4        4       2017       53  53  46
```

Following code is the one im trying to use, using only Group as a lookup i get a value

```
=INDEX(DataList,MATCH([@Group]:[@Division],DataList[Group]:DataList[Division],0),MATCH(TEXT($A$1,"mmm"),DataList[#Headers],0))
```

I have tried different variations,

- Binding the results together with an `&`,
- Tried binding just one result with `&` and the other one with a simple `:`

nothing has produced a good result in some cases i get a result, in others i do not get anything.

If i only use Group as a lookup term it's not an issue, it returns the correct value, but I'm trying to Index match two cells with two other cells.

I have evaluated the code and it does not return a value and I do not know what i'm doing incorrectly

Comment: Isn't `=INDEX(DataList,MATCH([@Group]&[@Division],DataList[Group]&DataList[Division],0),MATCH(TEXT($A$1,"mmm"),DataList[#Headers],0))` working properly?

Comment: This was one of the things i tried first, [@Group]&[@Division] returns correct value However DataList[Group]&D‌​ataList[Division] Return #VALUE!&#VALUE!

However if you have only DataList[Group] it returns information fine it sounds very strange for me and it's driving me mad, ever so slightly.

Comment: What if you replace `,DataList[Group]&D‌​ataList[Division]` by `,INDIRECT(DataList[Group])&INDIRECT(D‌​ataList[Division])` inside that formula?

Comment: `{=INDEX(DataList,MATCH([@Group]&[@Division],DataList[Group]&D‌​ataList[Division],0)‌​,MATCH(TEXT($A$1,"mm‌​m"),DataList[#Header‌​s],0))}` will work but must be confirmed using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to be an array formula.

Comment: @AxelRichter That did the trick! Thank you!